How to Secure Microservices in a Spring Boot Environment to Only Allow Access Through API Gateway with Token Authentication?
I’ve integrated an identity security service with my API Gateway (running on port 8080) and secured it with token-based authentication in a Java Spring Boot microservices environment. The API Gateway works as expected with token-based authentication.
However, I’m facing an issue where the individual microservices (running on ports 8083, 8084, etc.) and even the security service itself are still accessible directly, without any authentication.
What is the best way to secure all these services, ensuring they are not accessible directly without tokens and can only be accessed through the API Gateway?
Any guidance or recommendations on how to properly secure these services and enforce token validation across all endpoints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I’ve come across suggestions like blocking the ports in Kubernetes, but this doesn’t seem scalable, especially when auto-scaling is involved.

Doing token validation in all endpoints involves connecting all microservice with auth-server or include auth logic in every service, this is not a good idea.
Solution:
I think best approach to authentication and authorization in a microservices architecture is using an API gateway with an auth-server to handle all authentication and authorization processes centrally and configure your microservices to accept requests only from the API gateway and other internal services, thereby blocking any other outside requests.
